# How do I add a reference to a Windows Universal C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am new on windows universal apps and Visual Studio 2015 projects and I can't find how to add a reference to the C++ project. I want to use LINQ and the namespace System.Linq can't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find how to add a reference to the C++ project. I want to use LINQ and the namespace System.Linq can't be found.

You cannot reference a .NET assembly LINQ to a UWP C++ project. You can only reference the UWP Windows Runtime Component to it.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on "References" in the solution explorer, and click "Add reference" in the pop-up menu. That will open the reference manager where you can select the reference you need. You can read more about the topic in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx).

[[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncOTA.png)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx)

Comment: I also did that and I found nothing except from this http://s17.postimg.org/v1gkupesf/unnamed.png

Comment: @John, it should be in the Core tab I think. Also, try to use the search field in the top-right to search for "LINQ"

Comment: core tab is empty... and I also searched it but nothing found

Comment: @John, well then it seems like some of the libraries didn't get installed with your visual studio

Comment: how can I find what is not installed and then install it?

Comment: sorry that I didnt mention that it is a C++ project!

Answer (score 0):

You No need to add additional reference to 'System.Linq' by default it is there. just add `using System.Linq;`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
```

Comment: I already tried that and it doesnt work. It says "system is undefined"

Comment: Did you write "system" or "System"?

Comment: Try to create new empty project and see it shows the same error. if that it can be some VS installation error.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya New Project -> Visual C++ -> Windows -> Universal ->.NET 4.5.2 -> blank app. I did it and gets the same error... How can I found what is missing and then install it?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya sorry that I didnt mention that it is a C++ project!

Comment: That doesn't look much like C++. Why did you include all the other using statements?